# PHP and Xvfb usage

Tags: php, linux, terminal, xvfb

I'm trying to execute firefox on a headless server to take screen shots of a website. I can do this fine from the terminal using

"DISPLAY=:12 firefox -saveimage http://www.google.com/".

The problem is when I try to do system("DISPLAY=:12 firefox -saveimage http://www.google.com"); doesn't work. I have a feeling that it's not executing in a normal shell environment. I went against my better judgment and gave the apache user an actual shell. If I su to apache and execute the command everything is fine and works as expected, but again it doesn't work from a system call. Any insight is very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.

I just needed to create a shell script that will call that for me. After playing with it for a while I got it working after adding `export HOME="/var/www/"` at the top of the script.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there's some dependency on the environment variables you have set up as a shell user that isn't fulfilled by the httpd's environment.  Before doing any heroics with the environment, though, I'd recommend capturing stderr from your job (by adding **`2>/tmp/imgcaperrlog`** to the end of it, for example) and seeing if it's making any complaints.

Comment: I tired that and it's not even executing. That's what made me think maybe the environment that php executes system calls in is some how different.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely different.  What you're doing is an X operation, so it'll depend on all the context going on there.  One thing you can do is compare your shell environment (**set** by itself to view) with the environment inside your script (**print_r($_ENV)** or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of research I get it working, I have the same problem with Xvfb and xfreerdp.
Seems that apache2 mod_php doesn't set a home for user www-data, so calling the php script from URL, make xfreerdp to crash, cause it needs to write into ~/.config/freerdp directory. By the other end, calling it from php CLI works, because the shell already have a home set in the environment.

Without use an external shell script, I get it works with:

```
<?php
exec("nohup Xvfb :12 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 -nolisten unix &");
exec("DISPLAY=:12.0 HOME=/home/www-data/ nohup xfreerdp /bpp:24 /size:1280x1024 /u:admin /p:\"XXXXXX\" /v:10.0.0.10 /cert-ignore &");
```

I add the `-nolisten unix` to avoid creation of `/tmp/.X11-unix/` folder by user www-data. That directory should be owned by root. (and I don't need that Xvfb listen to a socket in my case)

@William Thanks a lot for the input, you save me.

Comment: What I read here is "I had a different though similar problem and helped it with the info from one of the existing answers. Thanks." That would be considered a non-answer. If you meant to contirbute an actual solution to the question at the top of this page please [edit] according to [answer] to make that more obviouis. Otherwise please delete this non-answer.